# Selecting Top Seller from Dealers Table with count of sales

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First off I have Agents and each Agent can have dealer(s).  I have an agent table containing all of my agents.  I have a contracts table where all of the sales are listed.  And I have a dealer table that attaches all of the dealers to agents.

```
SELECT a.agent_name, COUNT(distinct c.dealer_number) as '# of Selling Dealers'
FROM agents a
inner join contracts c on c.agent_number = a.agent_number
inner join dealers d on d.agent_number = a.agent_number 
group by agent_name
```

For example this query if I ran it right now would return

```
Agent Name     # of selling Dealers
Agent #1            6
```

What I now need to figure out is who is the top seller and how much they sold.  This info would be in the contracts table.

So as in the example `Agent #1` has 6 dealers who have made sales.  Lets pretend `Dealer #5` of that list has the most sales.

So it should return as follows:

```
Agent Name     # of selling Dealers      Top Dealer      Volume
Agent #1            6                     Dealer #5        24
```

I would like to return the dealer_name of the top seller and how many sales they got (also in the contracts table).

**Additional Info**

Each line in the contracts table counts as a sale.  It will have a `dealer_name`, `dealer_number` and `agent_name`, `agent_number`

agents table has agent_name, agent_number
dealers table has dealer_name, dealer_number, agent_number
contracts table has agent_number, dealer_number

Comment: How dealers linked to agents? a.dealer_number, is it error? It should be 'inner join dealers s on s.dealer_number = c.dealer_number'?

Comment: @Alsin Yeah that line contains an error I will update it and fix it.  It should be `inner join dealers d on d.dealer_number= a.dealer_number`

Comment: @Alsin you could also group `d.dealer_number on c.dealer_number` as well.

Comment: So `dealer_number` is a field of `agents` table?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I thought it was but double checking I was incorrect.  The only way to link a dealer to an agent is as follows. `join on a.agent_number = d.agent_number`.  My apologies to all I will update question.

Comment: 'each Agent can have dealer(s)' so dealer_number can't be column in Agents, isn't it? dealer_number stated in a contract, so Agents linked to Dealers over Contracts, is it correct?

Comment: @Alsin Correct I messed up the original post.  I took out a lot of the code I thought would be confusing to the question and broke it down to just the info I needed and ended up confusing my self. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT
    m.agent_name, 
    max_dealer_contract_sales,
    dealer_name
FROM 
    (SELECT
        agent_name, 
        MAX(dealer_contract_sales) AS max_dealer_contract_sales
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            agent_name, 
            dealer_name,
            COUNT(dealer_name) AS dealer_contract_sales
        FROM 
            contracts 
        GROUP BY 
            agent_name, 
            dealer_name) c
    GROUP BY
        agent_name) m INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        agent_name, 
        dealer_name,
        COUNT(dealer_name) AS dealer_contract_sales
    FROM 
        contracts 
    GROUP BY 
        agent_name, 
        dealer_name) c ON
        m.agent_name = c.agent_name AND
        max_dealer_contract_sales = dealer_contract_sales
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with AgentPerformance as
(
  SELECT agent_number, count(distinct c.dealer_number) as SellingDealers
  FROM contracts
  GROUP BY agent_number, 
), DealerPerformance as
(
  SELECT agent_number, dealer_number, count(*) DealerSalesCnt
  FROM contracts
  GROUP BY agent_number, dealer_number,
), TopDealersTmp as
(
  SELECT agent_number, dealer_number, DealerSalesCnt,
    row_number() over (partition by agent_number order by DealerSalesCnt desc) rn
  FROM DealerPerformance
), TopDealers as
(
  SELECT agent_number, dealer_number, DealerSalesCnt
  FROM TopDealersTmp
  WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT a.agent_name, ap.SellingDealers, d.dealer_name, td.DealerSalesCnt
FROM AgentPerformance ap
  join agents a
    on ap.agent_number = a.agent_number
  join TopDealers td
    on ap.agent_number = td.agent_number
  join dealers d
    on d.dealer_number = td.dealer_number
```

In AgentPerformance I calculate amount of selling dealers.

In DealerPerformance I calculate how many sales every dealer has (to choose the best one later).

In TopDealersTmp I re-number dealers according to performance starting from top performers for each agent.

In TopDealers I select only top performers.

In final select I pull names by numbers and do output.